# Gtk Window Non-Responsive During Selenium Automation

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, gtk3

Good Afternoon :) Having a problem with my Python3 Gtk3 application and Selenium WebDriver (ChromeDriver). Also, using Linux if it matters.

Basically, the user presses a button to start the Selenium webdriver automation and then as the automation process is going, it 'SHOULD' give feedback to the user in the GUI (See Content.content_liststore.append(list(item)) and LogBox.log_text_buffer).

However, it's not adding anything into the content_liststore until after fb_driver.close() is done. In the meantime, the Gtk window just "hangs".

Now, I've been looking into multithreading in hopes of the GUI being responsive to this feedback but I've also been reading that Selenium doesn't like multithreading (but I presume thats running multiple browsers/tabs (which this is not)).

So, my question is; Is multithreading the go-to fix for getting this to work?

```
            # ELSE IF, FACEBOOK COOKIES DO NOT EXIST, PROCEED TO LOGIN PAGE
            elif os.stat('facebook_cookies').st_size == 0:
                while True:
                    try: # look for element, if not found, refresh the webpage
                        assert "Facebook" in fb_driver.title
                        login_elem = fb_driver.find_element_by_id("m_login_email")
                        login_elem.send_keys(facebook_username)
                        login_elem = fb_driver.find_element_by_id("m_login_password")
                        login_elem.send_keys(facebook_password)
                        login_elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
                    except ElementNotVisibleException:
                        fb_driver.refresh()
                        StatusBar.status_bar.push(StatusBar.context_id, "m_login_password element not found, trying again...")
                        ProblemsLog.text_buffer.set_text("Facebook has hidden the password field, refreshing page...")
                    else:
                        query_elem = fb_driver.find_element_by_name("query")
                        query_elem.send_keys(target)
                        query_elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
                        break

                m_facebook_url_remove = "query="
                m_facebook_url = fb_driver.current_url.split(m_facebook_url_remove, 1)[1] # Remove string before "query="
                facebook_url = "https://www.facebook.com/search/top/?q=" + m_facebook_url # Merge left-over string with the desktop url

                StatusBar.status_bar.push(StatusBar.context_id, "Facebook elements found")
                fb_title = fb_driver.title
                fb_contents = [(target_name.title(), "Facebook", facebook_url)]
                for item in fb_contents:
                    Content.content_liststore.append(list(item))
                #progress_bar.set_fraction(0.10)
                LogBox.log_text_buffer.set_text("Facebook Search Complete")

                with open('facebook_cookies', 'wb') as filehandler:
                    pickle.dump(fb_driver.get_cookies(), filehandler)

                fb_driver.close()
```

I've considered it not working because of the 'while' loop, but another piece of code doesn't have a loop and does the exact same thing, it waits for Selenium to finish before adding content to the GUI.

Additionally, the user can select multiple websites to do this with, so the application can first go to Facebook (do it's business then close), go to LinkedIn (do it's business then close) and so fourth. And it still waits for all the Selenium code to finish before adding anything to the Gtk GUI.

I really hope that makes sense! Thank you :)

Comment: You need to run your Selenium script on a thread that is not the one running the GUI.

Comment: Thank you, you and Giedrius.S have pointed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your`s question is the answer you are lookig for. Take a read here https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/PyGObject/Threading